# What is the need of AcceptRejectRule and EnforceConstraints?

Tags: ado.net, constraints

net and had been trying to learn how this constraint mechanics wok with the tables and datasets. It's all getting so confusing when I came to know that ForeignKeyConstraint has DeleteRule/UpdateRule where you can set None. Then

why do we have AcceptRejectRule? How could it's cascade be used for both accepting and rejecting? What in the end is EnforceConstraints for then?

All these DeleteRule/UpdateRule = None, AcceptRejectRule = None and EnforceConstraints = false look same to me. Can anyone please tell me what is the difference. Is there a resource where I can read and understand to make things more clear. MSDN din't work for that matter.

This might not be the right place to ask this question. Apologies for the same. but please give me resources..

Answer (score 0):

The difference is *when* these rules are applied:

- AcceptRejectRule: When DataTable.AcceptChanges or DataTable.RejectChanges is called
- DeleteRule: As soon as the row is deleted
- UpdateRule: As soon as the row is modified

EnforceConstraints is a much broader setting that disables checking any constraints, but it does not affect how changes are cascaded.